# Optimizing the deployment for serverless applications

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

If i have the previous deployment package generated using `serverless package` handy, is there a way only changed lambdas and new lambdas get deployed and the unchanged lambdas are skipped.

What would be correct way to go about this? What other things can I look at to optimize the deployment process for enterprise applications.

Comment: I think it's an open issue: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3932

Comment: I think newer versions work the similar way - deploy only changes.

-what I do:
1- serverless invoke local -f function-name (always to this to test locally)
2- serverless deploy -v (deploys all functions - shd do this even while creating a new function)
3- serverless invoke -f function-name (to check if its deployed and executing on the cloud)